# "Could not find a part of the path" for windows client

Tags: c#, .net

I have a WPF client app. I'm try to get access to `c:\programdata\`, which I can clearly see is available. When I use File.Copy() and `c:\programdata\` as the destination, I get this error:

> Could not find a part of the path

Anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: Can you give us the full error?

Comment: Could not find a part of the path 'c:\\programdata\\'

Comment: show your code more detail

Comment: Could you please include the code

Comment: [File.Copy()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx) expects a ***file name*** as destination, not a directory

Comment: You should remove the `wpf` tag since this isn't related to it in any way. It's just a directory access issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [File.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation states that `destFileName` is:

> The name of the destination file. **This cannot be a directory or an existing file.**

You say you are passing `C:\\programdata\\`. That is a directory. You have to provide the path and the file name.

For example:

```
File.Copy("C:\\programdata\\source.txt", "C:\\programdata\\dest.txt");
```